# moodle apache centos 7

Tags: linux, apache, centos, centos7, moodle

Amigos tengo un problema con mi moodle tengo un subdominio que apunta a la ip de mi servidor de apache, resulta que pongo la ip 10.10.10.0/moodle/ y llega normal, ahora pongo mi subdominio que es moodle.escuelasip.com, y resulta que automáticamente me sobre escribe el subdominio por la ip queda asi: 10.10.10.0/moodle/ no queda con el subdominio que tengo en las configuraciones; las configuraciones en /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin usuario-admin@moodle.escuelasip.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
ServerName moodle.escuelasip.com
ServerAlias moodle.escuelasip.com

Alias /moodle "/var/www/html/moodle/"
<Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
#ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/moodle.example.com-error_log
#CustomLog /var/log/httpd/moodle.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

no entiendo por que realiza ese cambio espero me puedan ayudar les agradezco.

Comment: Bienvenido, Carlos. ¿Dónde pones la URL? ¿En la propia máquina que está configurada como servidor? ¿En otra de tu propia LAN? ¿En una máquina ajena a tu LAN? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Ademas de lo que te preguntan arriba, el `ServerAlias` te sobra si es el mismo que el `ServerName` lo mismo que el `Alias`. Quita los por si alguno está interfiriendo en el resto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amigos gracias a los que me ayudaron como solucione el problema resulta que para que funcione con el dominio y todo funciona bien hasta que cambie el dominio por la ip siempre teneis que modificar tambien moodle para que no realice este tipo de cambion gracias a los que me ayudaron.